# showInfoWindow() function doesn't work in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I have a google map with some markers and all of them have title and snippet. I store markers in a HashMap. I want to display title and snippet with showInfoWindow() function when a button clicked.
this is my code :

```
Marker m = getMarker(location); //this function return marker from HashMap with its location
if(m!=null)
    m.showInfoWindow();
```

m is not null, but showInfoWindow() doesn't work

debug output:
[image]

m.getTitle() log :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
    Marker m = getMarker(location);
if(m!= null){
    m.showInfoWindow();
}
```

The Marker object will be null if the marker has not been rendered on the map yet so be sure to check that the marker object is not null before using it.

Comment: Can you share the debug output

Answer (score 0):

For showing `infoWindow` your marker must be have a title.

```
 MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(location)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(aBitmapFile))
                .title("The Title"); //here is title
        mapPoint p = new mapPoint(lat, lng);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

then you can call: `.showInfoWindow();` on your marker.

Comment: it has title. see debug output

Comment: can you log the title of marker by calling ```marker.getTitle()``` ?